# How do I integrate a swagger file with aws_apigateway

Tags: aws-cdk

I want to use aws_apigateway and use a swagger file to define the api, how do I code this using AWS CDK either in python or TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround [here](https://martinmueller.dev/cdk-swagger-eng/), but so far (22/6/2022) is still in the CDK roadmap (issue [ref](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/723))

The workaround involves some manual steps and initial swagger extraction from CDK init, then it can be fed in somehow.